# inserting or updating values into null textboxes

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

```
    public void Updatecottonpurchase(int slipno, int basicprice, int premium, int totalamountpaid, int weight, int totalamountbasic, int totalamountpremium, int yeildestimates, int farmercode)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=TANYA-PC;Initial Catalog=biore1;Integrated Security=True");

        try
        {
            string sqlQuery = "UPDATE cottonpurchse SET slipno = '" + slipno + "' , basic price = '" + basicprice + "' , premium = '" + premium + "' , totalamountpaid = '" + totalamountpaid + "' , weight = '" + weight + "' , totalamountbasic = '" + totalamountbasic + "' , totalamountpremium = '" + totalamountpremium + "' , yeildestimated = '" + yeildestimates + "' WHERE farmercode = '" + farmercode + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConn);
            sqlConn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConn.Close();
        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            sqlConn.Close();
        }

        finally
        {
            sqlConn.Close();
        }
    }
```

this is what ive done now yet nothing happens! i want to beable to update the null values but nothing happens! please help

Comment: How are you trying to add/update the record?

Comment: im trying to do it through winforms! u see i have many textboxes tht are null now when i enter the values do i have to insert or update and how?

Comment: string queryString = "UPDATE cottonpurchase SET  slipno=InputSlipNoHere WHERE farmercode=2";
            try

Comment: What is your data access method?

Comment: Just reading what you say is happening and reading the code above my guess is that a different event is firing than you are expecting.  You may want to debug and find out which event is firing and figure out why it is that one.

Comment: it doesnt show anything a new row keeps adding when i dont want that to happen i just want to update or insert values in the null textboxes

Comment: can you please help me i really need to know how this is done?

Comment: @tanya: Your request to "insert values in the null textboxes" is impossible and makes no sense.  You seem to have a [confusion of ideas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Babbage#Quotations) that I do not believe can be resolved here.  Perhaps, however, what you are really interested in is [some information on using SQL parameterized queries and parameterized updates in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebxy9a8b(v=VS.90).aspx)?

Comment: see i have three textboxes that are not null and contain values, now , i dont have the information to fill in the other textboxes with any values so i have kept them as null, but later on when i do get the information to fill in those null textboxes , now here i dont knw what to do?? can u give me a suggestion?

Comment: @tanya: Databases do not contain textboxes.  Do you mean that you have a form with [`TextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox(v=VS.100).aspx) instances, and some of those (non-null) textbox instances have a null `Value`?  Are you trying to populate the textbox values with values from the database, or are you trying to create/update database rows with values from the textboxes?  Or do you mean something completely different?

Comment: @tanya you're SQL command look weird. E.g. slipno = 'slipno' I would have expected slipno to be a number (bsed on the name) and the same for fields named *amount however you are trying to assign a text value to them in your update and you then go and used them as booleans in the where clause

Comment: since im not going to be entering any values into these textboxes right now , i thought i would leave them null, so now i just want to update them and replace the null but im not sure what and how to do it!

Answer (score 1):

This SQL code:

```
UPDATE TABLE cottonpurchase SET  slipno= WHERE farmercode=
```

Does nothing, you need to add parameters,
see: http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx

You need to change the code into:

```
....
string queryString = 
     "UPDATE TABLE cottonpurchase SET slipno=@slipno WHERE farmercode=@farmercode"; 
try       
{          
  connection.Open();          
  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);

  //define parameters used in command object
  SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
  param.ParameterName = "@slipno";
  param.Value         = inputfromsomewhere;

  SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
  param.ParameterName = "@farmercode";
  param.Value         = inputfromsomewhereelse;

  //add new parameter to command object
  command.Parameters.Add(param);


  int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();          
  //if result = 1 the update is performed         
} 
......
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add or choose a column for use as the primary key. The primary key should uniquely identify a row, and is used to locate the row to update.

Comment: no but i will be doing it for many rows! not only one infact for all the rows

Comment: please help me i really am stuck with this dont understand what to do

Comment: @Tanya - You need to post the C# you wrote that at least attempts it.  If you don't understand the different between INSERT and UPDATE then do some research.

Comment: i know the difference i just dont know what to use to fill in those null values???